# Render twig HTML string with twig-variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some html buttons I want to render with twig. This is the HTML:

```
<a href="/Worklog/editWorklog?worklogid={{worklog.id}}&customerid={{worklog.customerid}}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit worklog</button></a>
```

I created a method in php to return the HTML string above which I pass in with twig like this:

```
{{ html.editWorklogButton|raw }}
```

But when the button is rendered with `raw` it also renders {{ worklog.id }} and {{ worklog.customerid }} `raw` of course, losing the id's, giving me href to:

```
localhost/Worklog/editWorklog?worklogid={{worklog.id}}&customerid={{worklog.customerid}}
```

which instead should be something like:

```
localhost/Worklog/editWorklog?worklogid=1&customerid=2
```

I've checked twig documentation, but can't find anything on this. Is this simply not possible to do?

Comment: Try `{{ dump(worklog) }}` to check what values you have.

Comment: Yep thx, have doublechecked this, the values in {{ worklog }} is correct, because if I use only the html showed above, the href outputs then with the correct worklogID and customerID using {{ worklog.id }} and {{ worklog.customerid }}. So either this is not possible or I'm missing something.

Comment: I think it may be because you are outputting this value dynamically.  So what you output it as `html.editWorklogButton|raw` - it will not interpret any of the values (you are saying you want it as is with the raw bit).

Comment: I believe you have a non-standard use-case. there's no built-in directive to render a *twig string within a twig template*, since it can't be considered safe, especially not with the surrounding context. this would suggest, that the template comes from the user (which would be unsafe).

Comment: [This](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html) might help (but I'm a bit unfamiliar with Twig so not 100% sure).

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi, I was curious though if this could work, but I thought this may be the case, that it is no case actually, so I'll do normal way. Thanks!

Comment: huh, Jeto is right, apparently there is a function since twig 2.8. use with care though ;o)

Comment: @jeto Eyh that worked like a charm! Thanks! I will consider if i should use it though, but cool to see it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`template_from_string` extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html).

> The `template_from_string` function loads a template from a string.

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
{{ include(template_from_string(html.editWorklogButton)) }}
```